# Array of Objects in C# wont serialize to JSON

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I am having some trouble getting an array of objects in C# to serialize to JSON.

My Code:

```
        friendlyNotification[] notifications = ns.friendlyNotifications.ToArray();
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(notifications);

        return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

The code above return the following:

```
[{}]
```

Does anyone have and idea why this isn't working? Something to do with the fact that I am trying to serialize an array?

Thanks.

Comment: does `notifications` contain any items?

Comment: Perhaps `ns.friendlyNotifications.ToArray()` is returning an empty array?  Seems like the first thing to check, no?

Comment: Do you know that there is data in the friendlyNotifications? Can you step through, what does it look like?

Comment: Yes, notifications contains data, I have verified that in debugging the code.

Comment: I'm quite sure that `friendlyNotification` is a class without public properties.  And `notifications` contains one element, thats why you get `[{}]` (`[{}]` has the meaning of an array with an empty object).

Comment: Please show your `friendlyNotification` class.

Comment: That was the issue! I had the values set as private! Thanks!

Comment: I've added my comment as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `friendlyNotification` is a class without public properties, and `notifications` contains only one element the json result is `[{}]`.

The json `[{}]` has the meaning, of an array with an empty object.